# Sequelize custom validation on JSON field

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I have defined the following sequelize model:

```
         {
            ID: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true
            },
            CategoryID: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                references: 'ProductCategories',
                referencesKey: 'id'
            },
            Name: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING(50),
                allowNull: false,
                unique: true
            },
            Dimensions: {
                type: DataTypes.JSON,
                validate: {
                    customValidator: (value: { Width: any; Height: any; Depth: any; }) => {
                        console.log('Running')
                        if (!validator.isNumeric(value.Width) || !validator.isNumeric(value.Height) || !validator.isNumeric(value.Depth) ||
                            !value.Width || !value.Height || !value.Depth) {
                            throw new Error('Error occured');
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            RequiredMinLevel: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            },
            CoverDays: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER
            }
        }
```

I also have the following express endpoint:

```
router.patch('/product', async (req, res) => {
    const id = req.body.ID
    const product = await Product.findById(id)
    if (product) {
        try {
            await product?.update(req.body);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e)
            return res.status(400).send(e)
        }
    } else {
        return res.status(404).send(`Product with ID ${id} not found`)
    }
    res.sendStatus(200)
})
```

The problem is that no matter what I do, when I call the endpoint with some data it only validates whether Height, Depth and Width exist, but if all of them exist, I don't even see the word "Running" being logged, it just skips the validation...
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation the custom validation should be like this:

```
class User extends Model {}
User.init({
  age: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  name: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING,
    allowNull: true,
    validate: {
      customValidator(value) {  //<--- validator should be funcation not JSON object like customValidator: (value)
        if (value === null && this.age !== 10) {
          throw new Error("name can't be null unless age is 10");
        }
      }
    }
  }
}, { sequelize });
```

I didn't run the code, maybe this changes works:

```
Dimensions: {
  type: DataTypes.JSON,
    validate: {
    customValidator(value: { Width: any; Height: any; Depth: any; }) => {
      console.log('Running')
      if (!validator.isNumeric(value.Width) || !validator.isNumeric(value.Height) || !validator.isNumeric(value.Depth) ||
        !value.Width || !value.Height || !value.Depth) {
        throw new Error('Error occured');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

See official docs: https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/validations-and-constraints/#allownull-interaction-with-other-validators

Comment: Sadly no, it doesn't work

Comment: Found a comment which is referring to your problem; [see this github comment](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/3698#issuecomment-105703204) you can use another validator **revalidator** to validate JSON type